# Joining two data frames based on the lower and upper limit of the target value in R

Tags: r, dataframe, join, match

I have two data frames, `df1` and `df2`. I would like to **join** these two in a way, that I add the target value from `df2` to `df1`. `df1` and `df2` are related via the column group and value. While in `df1`, I have a specific value, in `df2` I have only lower and upper limit of the applicable value.

I believe the task should be clear if we look at `df1` and `df2`.

```
df1 <- data.frame(group = c("A","B","C","D"),
                  value = c(15, 0, 40, 70))

df2 <- data.frame(group = c("A","A","A","A",
                            "B","B","B","B",
                            "C","C","C","C",
                            "D","D","D","D"),
                  lower_limit = c(0, 25, 60, 91,
                                  0, 35, 70, 92,
                                  0, 45, 80, 93,
                                  0, 55, 90, 94),
                  upper_limit = c(25, 60, 91, 100, 
                                  35, 70, 92, 100, 
                                  45, 80, 93, 100, 
                                  55, 90, 94, 100),
                  target = c("AGE0", "AGE1", "AGE3", "AGE4",
                             "AGE0", "AGE1", "AGE3", "AGE4",
                             "AGE0", "AGE1", "AGE3", "AGE4",
                             "AGE0", "AGE1", "AGE3", "AGE4"))
```

Using a nested for and if loops, I can perform this task. But my original data is much bigger, and I can’t use this loop. I am sure there is a much easier solution for my task. Any suggestions?

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df1)){
  subset_string = df1[i, 1]
  target_value = df1[i, 2]

  df2_subset <- df2[df2$group == subset_string, ]

  for (j in 1:nrow(df2_subset)){

    temp_sequence <- seq(from = df2_subset[j, 2], to = df2_subset[j, 3] - 1)
    if  (target_value %in% temp_sequence){
      target_string <- df2_subset[j, 4]
    }

    df1[i, 3] <- target_string
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about wanted result. Maybe with sdqldf:

```
df1 <- data.frame(group = c("A","B","C","D"),
                  value = c(15, 0, 40, 70))

df2 <- data.frame(group = c("A","A","A","A",
                            "B","B","B","B",
                            "C","C","C","C",
                            "D","D","D","D"),
                  lower_limit = c(0, 25, 60, 91,
                                  0, 35, 70, 92,
                                  0, 45, 80, 93,
                                  0, 55, 90, 94),
                  upper_limit = c(25, 60, 91, 100, 
                                  35, 70, 92, 100, 
                                  45, 80, 93, 100, 
                                  55, 90, 94, 100),
                  target = c("AGE0", "AGE1", "AGE3", "AGE4",
                             "AGE0", "AGE1", "AGE3", "AGE4",
                             "AGE0", "AGE1", "AGE3", "AGE4",
                             "AGE0", "AGE1", "AGE3", "AGE4"))

library(sqldf)
sqldf("select a.*, b.target
         from df1 a
         left join df2 b
           on a.`group` = b.`group`
             AND a.value >= b.lower_limit 
             AND a.value <= b.upper_limit")

# group value target
#1     A    15   AGE0
#2     B     0   AGE0
#3     C    40   AGE0
#4     D    70   AGE1
```

Comment: Yes! This is it... And this should also work on my big df. Thank you.

Comment: You can shorten this slightly with `a.value between b.lower_limit and b.upper_limit`

Answer (score 3):

`data.table` approach could be

```r
library(data.table)

setDT(df2)[setDT(df1), .(group, value, target), 
           on = .(lower_limit <= value, upper_limit >= value, group)]
```

which gives

```
   group value target
1:     A    15   AGE0
2:     B     0   AGE0
3:     C    40   AGE0
4:     D    70   AGE1
```

**Sample data:**

```
df1 <- structure(list(group = structure(1:4, .Label = c("A", "B", "C", 
"D"), class = "factor"), value = c(15, 0, 40, 70)), .Names = c("group", 
"value"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", 
"D"), class = "factor"), lower_limit = c(0, 25, 60, 91, 0, 35, 
70, 92, 0, 45, 80, 93, 0, 55, 90, 94), upper_limit = c(25, 60, 
91, 100, 35, 70, 92, 100, 45, 80, 93, 100, 55, 90, 94, 100), 
    target = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("AGE0", "AGE1", "AGE3", 
    "AGE4"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("group", "lower_limit", 
"upper_limit", "target"), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")
```

---

**Update:** as per OP's request `dplyr` solution is

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = "group") %>%
  filter(value >= lower_limit, value <= upper_limit) %>%
  select(group, value, target)

#  group value target
#1     A    15   AGE0
#2     B     0   AGE0
#3     C    40   AGE0
#4     D    70   AGE1
```

Comment: Indeed. =) Thank you all for your help and time.